# Customizing Window Vista Sample Existing Wrap Credential Provider

Tags: visual-studio-2013, credential-providers

I am wrapping the password credential provider and adding an extra password 
field. I have it set up so I can do my own password validation logic and 
work with the extra field.I have created the field already but i am unable to understand where to apply the logic in the code section for validation.Can anyone specifically point to the functions in the credential provider to do this?

Answer (score 0):

its not in the CP itself, look on https://github.com/LastSquirrelIT/MultiOneTimePassword-CredentialProvider
for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can either stop the credential provider from completing serialization in the `GetSerialization` method, or you can implement and register a [sub authentication filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/subauth/nf-subauth-msv1_0subauthenticationfilter)

If going the filter route, you will need to come up with some shared secure process for sharing the password between the credential provider and the LSA, which is not trivial.